# INCLUDE Code on Web?

Tags: include

One can `include` another code as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{code1}
\include{code2}
\include{code3}
\end{document}
```

Can I let this code to `include` another code in GitHub? For example, suppose I have the code whose address is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/code2.tex`. Sorry for this silly question.

Comment: The typical approach would be to download the file first and then just include it manually. Otherwise it wouldn't work without internet, the document might change etc. If you really want to do this, you probably need either LuaTeX or must enable shell escape. But if you enable shell escape you allow the file from the internet to execute arbitrary code on your system, so then you really have to trust the source.

Comment: Thanks. Scraping seems to be unavailable.

Comment: Hmmm, if the code you need to include is from github, then it must reside in your local repo too, so the usual includes would work. Whenever you do a `git pull` you get the files updated and your overall document updates. I am missing the real need to include remote files ...